# Primeng FormData File Upload to Spring Boot not working

Tags: angular, spring-boot, multipartform-data, primeng

I am trying to upload file from Angular version (13.3.8) , Primeng (13.2.1) to Spring Boot as Multipart File, But i am not able to get the file in the post method (status: 415, error: 'Unsupported Media Type')

File Upload Component

```
 <p-card header="Import file"> 
  <p-fileUpload
    customUpload="true"
    (uploadHandler)="onUpload($event)" 
  [multiple]="false"
    accept=".stk">
  </p-fileUpload>
</p-card>
```

Component.ts

```
 onUpload(event):any {
    if (event.files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const file = event.files[0];

      this.service.importFile(file).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        // Handle success response
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        // Handle error response
        console.error(error);
      }
);
}
```

Service

```
importFile(file: File) : Observable<any>{
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //this is the important step. You need to set content type as null
    headers.set('Content-Type', null);
    headers.set('Accept', "multipart/form-data");
    headers.set('encType', "multipart/form-data");
    let params = new HttpParams();
    return this.http.post(baseUrl+"/uploadFile", formData, {  headers ,params});
    
  }
```

Spring boot

```
@PostMapping(value = "/importStackup", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<String> importStackSet(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multiPart) {
//code
}
```

Error :

```
[36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `request` method instead of the `post` one could help.

If you take a look at the `HttpClient` jsdoc here is what you can find:

```js
    /**
     * Constructs a request that interprets the body as a `Blob` and returns
     * the full event stream.
     *
     * @param method  The HTTP method.
     * @param url     The endpoint URL.
     * @param options The HTTP options to send with the request.
     *
     * @return An `Observable` of all `HttpEvent`s for the request,
     * with the response body of type `Blob`.
     */
```

So in your case that would give something like that:

```js
importFile(file: File) : Observable<HttpEvent<Blob>> {
  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file, file.name);
  const request = new HttpRequest('POST', `${baseUrl}/uploadFile`, formData);
  return this.http.request(request);
}
```